# Angular2 router 3.0.0-beta.2 hostComponent

Tags: angular, angular-routing

When I was using router-depracated I check a component name like this:

```
  this.componentName = this.router.hostComponent.name;
```

But after upgrading to 3.0.0-beta.2 I get an error "Property 'hostComponent' does not exist on type 'Router'" What can I use in new  router instead of  hostComponent.name?

Answer (score 1):

In routed components you can use

```
constructor(route: ActivatedRoute) {
  this.componentName = route.component;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. Btw route.component  returns a function of the type string, isn't it odd?

Comment: I saw it when I tried it in a Plunker but I wasn't wondering too much. Many things in TS/JS land are quite weird to me, so this was no surprise ;-) (I'm mostly using Dart)